# Excel VBA Check for specific value in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a big trouble with my situation right now. My question is, is there any way I can delete the cell contents if its cell value has a string `Total Attachment Size:` ?

I have this part but don't know how to proceed. Been searching in the net for any ideas, but unfortunately it is not enough.

```
dim lastrow as integer
dim ws as worksheet

set ws = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1")

lastrow = ws.cells(rows.count, 8).end(xlup).row

if ws.range("H" & lastrow) contains `Total Attachment Size: ` then 
    ws.range("H" & lastrow).clearcontents
    lastrow = ws.cells(rows.count, 8).end(xlup).row

end if
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `If Instr(ws.range("H" & lastrow), "Total Attachment Size: ") > 0 Then` (or just `If ws.range("H" & lastrow) = "Total Attachment Size: " Then` if you want it to exactly match).

Answer (score 0):

This is as per your code, if you want to check all H column values then let me know, we can run a loop and clear all cells containing the value

```
Dim str As String
On Error Resume Next
str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("Total Attachment Size: ",Sheet1.Range("H" & Sheet1.Range("H500000").End(xlUp).Row).Value, 1)

If Err.Number = 0 Then

Sheet1.Range("H" & Sheet1.Range("H500000").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

End If
```