# Find text "testing" in a particular cell and check condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have some description text in  column "F". e.g. are

```
f1= P&PES - INTEROPERABILITY TESTING & VALIDATION SRVCS 
f2= CMT-PEL-PRODUCT ENGINEERING 
f3 = AO-TESTING-TESTING EXCELLENCE
```

Now I want to run a loop which will take individual cell into consideration and check if value in particular cells contains "testing".

If it contains "testing" then there are some conditions which I want to execute.

If it does not contains "testing" word then next cell wil be checked like f2 will be checked and so on.

The loop should go on till there is a value. Below is the code I have written but it only works for the first time when it finds the value testing in f1 when it checks for f2 it does not find testing word and then it throws an error error."Object variable or with block variable not set" and the macro stops.

Code below:

```
Dim Atdes As Integer
Dim Lamt As Integer
Dim Tcr As Integer

OG = 2
Oid = 3
row1 = 3
Lamt = 10
Tcr = 12
Atdes = 6
columnAA = 27
columnAB = 28
columnAC = 29
columnAD = 30
columnAE = 31

Do While Sheets("BH_Testing Practice_0_FY17_Sale").Cells(row1, 1).Value <> ""

    ' To find testing word
    Sheets("BH_Testing Practice_0_FY17_Sale").Cells(row1, 6).Select
    If Selection.find(What:="testing", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Then

        Sheets("BH_Testing Practice_0_FY17_Sale").Cells(row1, columnAA).Value = "CAT"
    End If
    row1 = row1 + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: are you looking to find "testing" only in one cell `Cells(row1, 6)`  - one cell that consits of Column "F" of current row ?  or the entire row ?

Comment: try the code in my answer below, see if it works for you

Comment: did you test any of the answers you got? some feedback would be nice

Comment: yes the one from clintB worked for me thanks

Comment: you do realize that in your case the `Instr` and `Like` functions behave the same ? In any way, accept his answer by clicking the little **V** next to his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instr instead of search. Its easier to use.

```
 set ws = Sheets("BH_Testing Practice_0_FY17_Sale")

 If( InStr(ws.Cells(row1, 1), SearchStr))>0) THEN
     ...
 END IF
```

Much like the comment posted to this question just recently:
[Excel VBA Check for specific value in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754813/excel-vba-check-for-specific-value-in-cell)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Like` function you can find if a certain cell contains the string of "testing" in it. Adding the wilcard sign (`*`) before and after the "testing" means that "testing" can appear also in the begining or the end of the entire cell's string.

(I commented some of the cariables in the code, not to get an error)

### Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindTesting()

Dim Atdes As Integer
Dim Lamt As Integer
Dim Tcr As Integer
Dim row1    As Long
Dim columnAA As Integer

'OG = 2
'Oid = 3
row1 = 3
Lamt = 10
Tcr = 12
Atdes = 6
columnAA = 27
'columnAB = 28
'columnAC = 29
'columnAD = 30
'columnAE = 31

With Sheets("BH_Testing Practice_0_FY17_Sale")
    Do While .Cells(row1, 1).Value <> ""
        ' check if current row Column F contains "testing"
        If .Cells(row1, 6) Like "*testing*" Then
            .Cells(row1, columnAA).Value = "CAT"
        End If

        row1 = row1 + 1
    Loop
End With

End Sub
```